# read values as string of yaml with libyaml

Tags: c, yaml, libyaml

I'm need simple example for using libyaml to get all keys+values as strings from yaml file.

lets say i have this yaml file:

```
Active Groups: 
    btcoex: yes
    datapath: no

Header:
    TLV_data_version: 1
    command id: 0xf1
    group id:   0x01
btcoex:
    enabel ATS:
        Active: yes
        Apply_point: APPLY_POINT_AFTER_ALIVE
        selection: 
            set: 1
            table: 3 
            cpu: 1
```

how can I just print all the keys and values?

Comment: Feel free to use this program as a start: https://github.com/yaml/libyaml/blob/master/tests/run-parser-test-suite.c

Comment: Please describe the problems you have with implementing this yourself. Mind that you should put effort in solving the problem yourself before asking here; SO is not a place to ask other people to write your code.